# form variables and session scope - browser back button

Tags: php, cakephp

I am looking for some good Design Pattern which should/can save the submitted form variables in Session and later can re-populate the form with session variables.

for example at my start page I have a search form with different Selectboxes and checkboxes.

On Submiting the form I save the form variables in session and on the search result page I have some more filter options to refine the result list ( these filter will also be saved in session )

I am trying to diffrenciate if I come on the page then I will save the form vaialble in session, and with get I will read session variables and populate the form vailable.

I am facing many issues if I use form's post method to submit the form. for example clicking browser back button will not render the page.

Is there any Pattern / Best Practice / Standard available to solve such problems?

Comment: Show your code...

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search & https://github.com/World-Architects/cakephp-query-param-preserver in combination